# Not showing total rows from table PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all the rows in the table and get the title and search the title in another table. If I echo the total number(816) of rows it's correctly showing. But if add the below code Its showing only(414) results from the table.

```
    $viewss1=$con->query("SELECT COUNT(reference_id) FROM reference WHERE 
    reference LIKE '%$paper_title%'");
    $cview1=$viewss1->fetch_row();
    $countt1=$cview1[0];
```

If I add it showing half results. Why was that?. I don't know why. MY full code attached below. Thank you.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=$con->query($sql);
$record=array();
if($result)
{
    if($result->num_rows)
    {
        while($row=$result->fetch_object())
        {
            $record[]=$row;
        }
    }
}
foreach($record as $r)
{
    $paper_title=$r->paper_title;
    echo $paper_title;
    // If i add the below code it shows half results.
    $viewss1=$con->query("SELECT COUNT(reference_id) FROM reference WHERE 
    reference LIKE '%$paper_title%'");

    $cview1=$viewss1->fetch_row();
    $countt1=$cview1[0]; 

    echo "<br>";
    echo $r->upload_paper_id; 
    echo $countt1;
    echo "<br>"; 

}
```

Comment: You have a where condition on the one and not the other...

Comment: Also note that `COUNT(reference_id)` is only counting rows where `reference_id` is not null, so even without the where clause, the number of results could be different.

Comment: It's not clear to me what specifically you're asking.  Which query appears to be returning the wrong information?  What is the exact runtime query you're executing after your SQL-injectible string interpolation?  When you execute that query manually on the database, what are the results?  What results are you expecting?  Why?

Comment: yes david.if i echo the total rows in table.it does not showing.It showing only half results.if i remove the mentioned query it will show the all rows($paper_title).why?

Comment: Yes got that goleztrol.Now how can i resolve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.If any any rows have the empty value,It will stop the loop.So better to check empty or not.